# Why is my code getting an unexpected EOF?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$output_form= true;
$output_message = "";

$fname = "";
$lname = "";
$address = "";
$city = "";
$state = "";
$zipcode = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // data posted
    
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    echo"</pre>";
    
    $fname = trim($_POST['fname']);
    $lname = trim($_POST['lname']);
    $address = trim($_POST['address']);
    $city = trim($_POST['city']);
    $state = trim($_POST['state']);
    $zipcode = trim($_POST['zipcode']);
    
    if (empty($_POST['fname']) || empty($_POST['lname']) || empty($_POST['address']) || 
    empty($_POST['city']) || empty($_POST['state']) || empty($_POST['zipcode'])) 
         $output_message = "<p> All fields are mandatory  </p>";
         $output_form = true;
    } else {
         $output_form = false;
    } 
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8" >
    
</head>

<body>
  
<?php
 if ($output_form) {
?>

<h1> HTML Forms </h1>
<h2> Customer Entry Form </h2>
    <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
 name="userform" target="_self">
        <?= $output_message ?>
 <table>
    <tr>
    
        <td>First Name:</td><td> <input name="fname" type="text" value="<?=$fname ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name:</td><td> <input name="lname" type="text" value="<?=$lname ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address:</td><td> <input name="address" type="text" value="<?=$address ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>City:</td><td> <input name="city" type="text" value="<?=$city ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>State:</td><td> <input name="state" type="text" value="<?=$state ?>" /></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Zip Code:</td><td> <input name="zipcode" type="text" value="<?=$zipcode ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>    
    <input name="submit" type="submit" />
    </form>

<?php
{
?>
    <h1> Output Form False</h1>
 
<?php
 } // end of/else form output
?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Currently receiving an unexpected End Of File error. I'm not sure why? Am I leaving something in or something out? I'm new to PHP and I cant make sense of why this does not work. I know this is a lot to read but any feedback helps. Hoping it is a simple fix for anyone out there. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you don't like the convenience of IDEs, you can always count the curlies yourself.

Comment: mismatched braces?  Try using the alternate format `<?php if($output_form): ?> ... html here ... <?php endif; ?>` as it’s much easier to keep track of